# how to know if form window frame is clicked?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find when a form frame is clicked.

I though using the `Click` or `Mouse Down` event would be fine.

However, no matter how many time I click on the frame of the form, the event doesn't trigger.

Why is this? Here is the event used.

```
        private void MainForm_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
          // Code
        }
```

Comment: possibly that the form frame is not at the top, so although you thought that you click it, something (transparent) is blocking it. I suggest you to debug by putting color of your frame, so you know if you are actually clicking it.

Comment: but double clicking it maximise the window. Doesn't it mean I'm clicking on it?

Comment: Main frame? Window frame? Double click Window frame (that contains title bar, minimize,max, close) will give you maximise, but main frame (the square under Window frame) won't unless you add the event handler. Do you want to add event handler on the Window Frame instead?

Comment: oups... sorry about it though it was called the frame... so yeah the window frame which is the upper part

Comment: I gave up on it and handle other events now... it's not exactl as I wanted....

Comment: Use a boolean in tge form click event.

Comment: but clickevent is not activated when clicking on the window frame. At least for me. Is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Please see file "MainForm.Designer.cs", you must be bound event "this.MouseDown":

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 12F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.Text = "MainForm";
            this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MainForm_MouseDown);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

Comment: those lines? already there:

            this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MainForm_MouseDown);
            this.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MainForm_MouseUp);

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you need access to lower level events you can always expose the win32 event WndProc which lets you peak, and "react to", windows messages. Windows OS is very much message based so most any (low level) message you need can be captured here,

Example (C#):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
     // use the 'm' struct
}
```

It's very much up to you, what you do with this "Message Pump" but most all window events will be "pumped" through this callback.

**EDIT 1**

If you have access to Visual Studio you can view all available events that fire using Spy++.

1. In Visual Studio click tools->spy++
2. In spy++ click Search -> Find Window
3. Launch your form application and drag the spy++ cross-hair to select the Frame of your app
4. This will locate your app in the spy++ app list. Right click the app in spy++ and click Messages

Now any messages you can use will be logged to the window so go to your app and click the frame. Spy++ will show all messages as they are sent from the OS.

Hope it helps

Comment: thx I cam across it 10 min ago. I'm able to intercept when left button is release, msg = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
However I really can't find a msg to find it as soon as btn is down?

Comment: Do you not get, WM_LBUTTONDOWN                  0x0201?

Comment: yes, I tried those 2:
const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

Comment: Late here for me (Central Time) however I'm curious as to the outcome so if you haven't figured it out by morning, I'll certainly check back...

Comment: thx a lot!! May go to sleep soon, it's late too and I've been loosing 5 hours on this

Comment: thx! I used Spy++. However no event is triggered specially when clicking on the frame (with minimise option, maximise option, etc...) I found on other forums that other people encoutered this problem